Permission Denied While Running .sh Script in Docker Container with Heroku Dyno Deployed with Github Actions
My goal is to run a docker container in Heroku. I can run the container in a local build. When I deploy with Github actions, logs say that the startup CMD in the dockerfile wasn't run due to a permission denied error.
I used Github actions because heroku container:push web gave me 405 Method Not Allowed, then I tried this, which did its part.
For reference, some files are as below:
Dockerfile:
# FINAL STAGE
FROM alpine

# Install packages
RUN apk update
RUN apk add nginx nginx-mod-http-brotli nodejs npm supervisor

# Server
WORKDIR /app/server
COPY server/package.json server/package-lock.json ./
RUN npm ci
COPY server/src src

# Client
WORKDIR /app/client
COPY --from=build client/dist dist

# supervisord and nginx
WORKDIR /app
COPY supervisord.conf .
COPY nginx.conf.template .

# Runtime scripts
WORKDIR /app
COPY scripts/fillNginxConf.js scripts/
COPY runtime.sh .

# Start
RUN chown -R nginx:nginx /app
RUN chown -R nginx:nginx /etc/nginx/
USER nginx
WORKDIR /app
CMD ["/app/runtime.sh"]

runtime.sh
#!/bin/sh
cd /app/scripts
node fillNginxConf.js
cd ..
supervisord -c supervisord.conf

The action completes but the app crashes and the Heroku logs are:
2024-11-22T12:48:56.893890+00:00 app[api]: Release v78 created by user berkan
2024-11-22T12:48:56.893890+00:00 app[api]: Deployed web (5b109766c096) by user berkan
2024-11-22T12:48:58.295090+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2024-11-22T12:49:03.404885+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `/app/runtime.sh`
2024-11-22T12:49:04.146069+00:00 app[web.1]: /bin/sh: /app/runtime.sh: Permission denied
2024-11-22T12:49:04.204831+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 126
2024-11-22T12:49:04.235181+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed

Some help would be appreciated, I am lost.

Try this,
# Runtime scripts
WORKDIR /app
COPY scripts/fillNginxConf.js scripts/
COPY runtime.sh .

#ADD THIS LINE
RUN chmod +x ./runtime.sh

# Start
RUN chown -R nginx:nginx /app
RUN chown -R nginx:nginx /etc/nginx/
USER nginx
WORKDIR /app
CMD ["/app/runtime.sh"]


When you copy a script over it doesn't automatically get the +x executable permission.
Hope this helps

That did the trick. Many thanks.
